# Why does this simple makefile only build one source file?

Tags: makefile

I have files `X.c` and `X.ispc` and I want to build a shared library `X.so` using the makefile.

However, the simple makefile below only gives me:

```
gcc -m32 -c X.c -o X.c.o
ispc -O2 --arch=x86 --target=sse4-i32x4 X.ispc -o X.ispc_o
gcc -m32 -Wl,-hash-style=sysv -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -nostdlib -shared X.c.o -o X.so
```

There is no X.ispc_o in the last step. May I know what did I do wrong?

```
ISPC=ispc
ISPCFLAGS=-O2 --arch=x86 --target=sse4-i32x4

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -m32 -Wl,-hash-style=sysv -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -nostdlib -shared

default: so

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        /bin/rm -rf objs *.o

obj := $(patsubst %.c, %.so, $(wildcard *.c))
so: $(obj)

%.so: %.c.o %.ispc_o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.ispc_o: %.ispc
        $(ISPC) $(ISPCFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.c.o: %.c
        $(CC) -m32 -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 2):

The automatic variable $< is the name of the first prerequisite.  What you want is $^.  This expands to a space delimited list of the names of all of the prerequisites.  If your info pages are installed

```
info make 'Automatic Variables'
```

will give you a complete listing of the variables like this.